# Angular 9 http.Get request with paramaters

Tags: angular, http-get

I am trying to send query parameters with a get request. This code always has an empty query {}. What am I missing?

```js
let p = new HttpParams().set('Test', "7878");
return this.http
  .get<Response>(environment.baseAPIUrl + route, 
    { 
      withCredentials: false, 
      headers: requestHeaders, 
      params: p, 
      responseType, 
      observe: observe as 'body'
    } 
  );
```

Comment: What do your mean with `This code always has an empty query {}.`?. How did you check it?

Comment: oh, I have an event object that I am just dumping to the log. Its an AWS lambda 
 called from angular 
  
 query: {},
  path: {},
  
called from postman

 query: { test: '34534' },
  path: {},

Comment: You should check the network tab of your browser's dev-tools to see what it is actually sending - maybe the issue is on the server side...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically your use of `HttpParams` seems okay and it's working for me.

Open my [Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-by9ny1):

- open the dev-tools (F12 in Chrome)
- go to the network tab
- now Refresh the stackblitz-browser frame: everything looks good:

[image]

just note, that the error-message (1) will not include the url-parameters